# How do i load item 5 per 5? in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im using PFQueryTableViewController to load all my data from parse. 
Currently it loads all the data at once, so in the future if i have many data it will mess up the user experience of users. How do i load it 5 per 5 whenever I scrolled down?

Here's the code

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class MainViewTable: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "product"
        self.textKey = "createdAt"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false

    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "product")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        return query
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        }

        if let titleName = object?["title"] as? String {
            cell.title.text = titleName
        }

        if let priceTitle = object?["price"] as? Int {
            cell.price.text = String(priceTitle)
            println(cell.price.text! + "Price")
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably loads in pages of 100 items, test it more

Comment: yeah, but how do i load it 5 per 5?

Comment: Why do you want to load 5 at a time? How big are your objects? Have you noticed any performance issues? There are limitations when you use the convenience of 3rd party classes, not sure if it will respect any limit you apply to the query and 5 items per request will lead to other latency issues anyway...

Comment: You can use skip combined with limit. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-query-constraints

Comment: I tried to used it but its just skipping 10 items, instead of loading 5 items per scrolling